# What does 付き合い悪くて mean?

Tags: meaning, translation, words, manga, sentence

[image]

Translation: **I'm a busy man**

I got this from the manga "Blue Period". The translation provided above is from the official translation. From my understanding, 付き合い indicates a relationship, specifically the state of knowing someone, so it does strike me as odd how the words (in the trans) was phrased. I guess it is kind of a paraphrase, but even then I don't understand what the original sentence mean and how it fits into the context.

Comment: Totally unrelated but 学ランにネクタイって・・・

Answer (score 1):

This individual is basically using "I'll be bad company" as a euphemism, in this case, for "excusing" their early departure.  I think what's going on with a lot of the translations, even the official ones, is not to aim for a *literal* translation but rather a translation that best captures the mood.

Comment: I thought he was 八虎 and he had just arrived. But I may be wrong. I thought he was she at first.

Comment: @aguijonazo thank you for the feedback. i was wondering exactly what the context was and who was who. perhaps i should have rendered it gender neutral.

Comment: No, gender is fine. The official (?) translation says "man". I just wanted to say I'm so clueless about the context and therefore I can be easily wrong.

Comment: I agree with agujunazo. It appears to me that Yatora had just arrived, and the first two guys spoke ill of Yatora without noticing he had been there. "Sorry for being an unsociable 優等生 (but I'm here today)!"

Comment: このマンガ途中まで読んだんですけど、八虎は、週末は朝まで付き合うけど、平日は、勉強するので夕方帰ります。この場面でも、八虎は立ち上がって、「ゴメンね、付き合い悪くて」って言って、家に帰りました。

Comment: Your original answer was not bad at all then. It may even be better than the current version.

Comment: @aguijonazo I'm a bit confused.  I don't have access to the manga in question and Chocolate filled in details I was unaware of when I first answered the question.  I had been under the impression that 八虎 was arriving, but according to Chocolate 八虎 was leaving.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you see your very first answer in the edit history?

Comment: @aguijonazo Touche!  Good point.  Hmmm.  I can't recollect why I changed my answer back then.

Comment: @naruto and I confused you, that's why.

Comment: @A.Ellett Maybe the anime is easier to find as reference? In the anime the dialogue it's the same and it's in the first episode a bit after one minute; it should be available on Netflix.